# Proof of Darboux vector formula

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $\alpha$ be a path in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with speed $v\neq 0$ (where $v$ is the speed) and $\boldsymbol{T'} \neq 0$. Let $\boldsymbol{w} = \tau v \boldsymbol{T} + \kappa v \boldsymbol{B}$, where $\tau$ is the torsion and $\kappa$ the curvature.

Prove: $\boldsymbol{w} \times \boldsymbol{T} = \boldsymbol{T'}$

This seems simple, but I'm weak on the algebra of vectors and thus seem to be spinning my wheels at a certain point.

Expanding $\boldsymbol{w}$, we have

$\boldsymbol{w} \times \boldsymbol{T} = (\tau v \boldsymbol{T} + \kappa v \boldsymbol{B}) \times \boldsymbol{T}$

$= (\tau v \boldsymbol{T}  \times \boldsymbol{T}) + (\kappa v \boldsymbol{B} \times \boldsymbol{T})$

$= (\tau v \boldsymbol{T}  \times \boldsymbol{T}) + ((\kappa v (\boldsymbol{T} \times \boldsymbol{N})  \times \boldsymbol{T}) ~$ (by definition of Binormal vector)

$= (\tau v \boldsymbol{T}  \times \boldsymbol{T}) + ((\kappa v (\boldsymbol{T} \times \boldsymbol{T}) \times (\boldsymbol{N} \times \boldsymbol{T})) ~$ (??)

Is this last step legit? Doesn't the cross product distribute over the cross product? But $\boldsymbol{T} \times \boldsymbol{T}$ would give us $\boldsymbol{0}$, and $\boldsymbol{0} \times (\boldsymbol{N} \times \boldsymbol{T})$ would give us $\boldsymbol{0}$ again. That doesn't seem right.

As for $\tau v \boldsymbol{T}  \times \boldsymbol{T}$, I'm told $\boldsymbol{B'} = c\boldsymbol{N}$ (where $c$ is a scalar that depends on $t$), and $\tau = \frac{c}{v}$. I'm not sure if I can even begin by saying $c = \frac{\boldsymbol{B'}}{N} = \frac{\boldsymbol{T} \times \boldsymbol{N'}}{N}$ since vector division is not defined, right?

Little help?

Comment: Forget the definition of $B$ as a cross product. Instead, remember that $T,N,B$ is a right-handed orthonormal triple.